# React - Sort by newst date in useState

Tags: reactjs

i have code this and i want sort newst date to the oldest date.
Than you my friend.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN1qZ.jpg)

```
const renderDataNews = (data) => {
    if (context.locale === 'en') { 
    return (
    <> 
      {data.map((news, index) => {
          return (
            <Col key={index} lg='4' md='6' sm='6' xs='12'>
            <Card>
            <CardBody> 
            <CardTitle className='text-right'>{moment(news.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}</CardTitle>
                    <li key={index}>{news.title_en}</li>
                    <p>{news.des_en}</p>
            </CardBody>
            </Card>
            </Col>
          )
        })}
   </>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using a methodology like explained here :
[How to sort an object array by date property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property)

```
data.sort((a,b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)).map( /* your mapping code */)
```